# How to import Java file into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have downloaded a JAVA FILE and I don't know how to import it in Eclipse.

Comment: Copy and paste to your project's src folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's a plain Java file (.java), just put it somewhere inside the `src` folder of your project. Also, you will have to change its package name, so if it says:

```
package com.some.package;
```

And you copy it to `src/com/your/app`, then you have to change the package name to this:

```
package com.your.app;
```

By the way, there's no "Import Java file" option in Eclipse, don't waste time looking for an automatic way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is take the file and drop it to the default workspace eclipse folder. Then open the eclipse and refresh the project

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new project out of it then follow:

New -> Java Project -> Create Project from existing source.

Give correct path and proceed further.